# What's wrong with my AWS CLI configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I'm attempting to use the AWS CLI tool to upload a file to Amazon Glacier. I installed `awscli` using `pip`:

```
sudo pip install awscli
```

I created a new AWS IAM group `example` with `AmazonGlacierFullAccess` permissions.

I created a new AWS IAM user `example` and added the user to the `example` group. I also created a new access key for the user.

I created a new AWS Glacier Vault `example` and edited the policy document to allow the `example` user to allow actions `glacier:*` with no conditions.

I then ran `aws configure` and added the "Access Key ID" and "Secret Access Key" as well as the default region.

When I run:

```
aws glacier list-vaults
```

I get the error:

```
aws: error: argument --account-id is required
```

If I add the account ID:

```
aws --account-id=[example user account ID] glacier list-vaults
```

I get this error:

```
A client error (UnrecognizedClientException) occurred when calling the ListVaults operation: No account found for the given parameters
```

I figured I might have gotten something in the group assignment wrong, so I added the `AdministratorAccess` policy directly to the `example` user. Now I can run commands such as `aws s3 ls`, but I still cannot `aws glacier list-vaults` without getting the `aws: error: argument --account-id is required` error.

Have I missed something in my AWS configuration? How can I further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Are you using your account number (12 digit numeric number) as your account id?

Comment: Apparently not...I'm using the "Access Key ID" from my IAM user. Where can I find my account ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like for `AWS Glacier` you need the account ID [List Vaults (GET vaults)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-vaults-get.html)

You can get your account id (12 digits) from `Support` page - Top right on your AWS dashboard.